# Convert MongoDB ObjectID to timestamp in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongomapper

How can I convert MongoDB IDs to their respective date? (I am not interested in using the Javascript technique with `getTimestamp()`...)

Answer (score 4):

In case you did not use `timestamps!` in MongoMapper or Mongoid, you can still get the created_at date from the ObjectID itself:

```
user = User.last
user.id
# => BSON::ObjectId('5a90731ddcd2d5008c000443')
user.id.generation_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
# => "2018-02-23 20:01"
```

For my future self...